# Switch from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.04 question

Tags: installation, 13.04

I am currently switching from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.04. When i download the .iso file from Ubuntu.com I notice that it said AMD64 and i have a intel cpu. Is there a certain version i need for intel chips.

Comment: the normal one is for X86 Intel systems with are 32 bit
the 64 bit systems are X86-64 or AMD64

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your computer's architecture. Check whether you have a 64 bit or 32 bit OS. 
If it is 64 bit you can choose either amd64 or i386.  If it is 32 bit you must choose i386.

Answer (score 0):

Nope , amd64 will work fine with you intel chips , its just the naming convention.